# PrimeFaces push endpoint(s) on Apache: AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL

Tags: apache, primefaces, atmosphere, primefaces-push

I have been successfully using `atmosphere 2.4.2` with `PrimeFaces 5.3` on `Tomcat8` and `Apache Lounge (Windows) 2.4.27` server upfront. Push is working fine, however, I just keep on receiving following info logger in Apache logs on almost every page refresh:

```
[Tue Jan 30 07:15:04.457748 2018] [proxy:warn] [pid 11408:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:52714] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /xxx-primefaces-portlet/primepush/xxx-push-endpoint. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule., referer: https://example.com/group/pages/x-page
```

My proxy mapping for push is as following:

```
ProxyPass /xxx-primefaces-portlet/primepush/ ws://127.0.0.1:8094/xxx-primefaces-portlet/primepush/
ProxyPassReverse /xxx-primefaces-portlet/primepush/ ws://127.0.0.1:8094/xxx-primefaces-portlet/primepush/
```

I have also tried with `mod_rewrite` and `ProxyPassMatch`. Push mapping gets resolved but the logger keeps on appearing. How can I overcome that logging?

Comment: mod_proxy_wstunnel is enabled?

Comment: Offcourse, `mod_proxy_wstunnel` is enabled, that is why push is working fine.

Comment: Note that PrimePush will be deprecated in PrimeFaces 6.2 and removed in later versions: https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-6-2-roadmap/

Comment: Okay, but for now we don't have such plan to upgrade PrimeFaces.